# Resource request: 3-4 page review of exponentials and logs

Tags: resource-request, exponential

I'm teaching a physics class that has a year of calculus as a prerequisite, but as so often happens, many of my students have forgotten a lot of the much more basic math from earlier classes. In particular, many don't seem to know how to manipulate logs and exponentials or how to do things like changing $2^x$ to a base-e exponential.

Question: Can anyone recommend a 3-4 page brief summary and review of these topics? I'm looking for something that my students can access for free online.

I found this, which seemed too brief for my purposes: https://wou.edu/mathcenter/files/2015/09/Exponents-and-Logarithms.pdf For example, it doesn't show what the graphs look like, it doesn't seem to explicitly show how to change the base of an exponential, and it doesn't make contact with calculus.

OpenStax College Algebra has a 100-page chapter that is much too lengthy and contains too much cruft for my purposes: https://assets.openstax.org/oscms-prodcms/media/documents/CollegeAlgebra-OP.pdf

The Wikipedia articles "Exponential" and "Exponentiation" have too little of the basic material and wander off into topics that I see as not very relevant, such as combinatorics.

Comment: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5255b01de4b065c225ebc251/t/5640ee53e4b0614733dad7b9/1447095891884/Summary+Sheet+CH+3.pdf

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is too narrow to be of general interest, and is best answered via google search or custom-writing a handout which meets these specific needs.